# How can I Fit Image inside Grid Layout

Tags: css, flexbox, grid

I am creating this layout

[image]

My code :

```
<div class="tour-grid"> 
        
          <div class="tgItem tg-left"> 
            <a href="" class="tgCard">
              <div class="tgCard__image ro-4">
                <img class="ro-4 js-lazy loaded" src="img/tours/3.png" alt="image" data-ll-status="loaded">
              </div> 
            </a>

          </div>

          <div class="tgItem tgChild"> 
            <a href="" class="tgCard">
              <div class="tgCard__image ro-4">
                <img class="ro-4 js-lazy loaded" src="img/blog/2/2.png" alt="image" data-ll-status="loaded">
              </div>  
            </a> 
          </div>

          <div class="tgItem tgChild"> 
            <a href="" class="tgCard">
              <div class="tgCard__image ro-4">
                <img class="ro-4 js-lazy loaded" src="img/blog/2/3.png" alt="image" data-ll-status="loaded">
              </div> 
            </a> 
          </div>
          
          <div class="tgItem tgChild"> 
            <a href="" class="tgCard">
              <div class="tgCard__image ro-4">
                <img class="ro-4 js-lazy loaded" src="img/tours/2.png" alt="image" data-ll-status="loaded">
              </div> 
            </a> 
          </div> 
        </div>
```

Check [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9z0atjvp/)

But grid are not equal and **image doesn't fit inside div**.

Right **div** height should adjust to left **col**

[image]

what is rules with grid system ? should i wrap 3 div into one. ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify your code like below

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.grid img:first-child {
  grid-area: span 3/span 2;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1074/600/400">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1074/300/200">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1074/300/200">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1074/300/200">
</div>
```

I have an article explaining this code and more: https://css-tricks.com/exploring-css-grids-implicit-grid-and-auto-placement-powers/#image-grid

Comment: .tg-left .tgCard__image {
    height: 100%;
}
.tour-grid .tgCard__image img:first-child {
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}